# Using jQuery to fill out a form element but value not passing to form action

Tags: php, jquery, post

All
I have the following form input element:

```
<input name="payment_amount" type="text" id="payment_amount" value="" disabled>
```

I then manipulate the value of this form element by using jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).on('click','#remaining_balance',function(){
    jQuery("#payment_amount").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    send_amount = jQuery("#value_to_transfer").val();
    jQuery("#payment_amount").val(send_amount);
});
```

When I click on that radio button it populates the value into my payment_amount field but when I submit the form the value doesn't get passed to my receiving page. Any idea why that it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disabled elements are not sent to the server. Enable it, send the data, then disable it again.

Comment: Alternatively, you could pass a hidden input instead and leave `#payment_amount` disabled.

Comment: @pete That's a good idea too. I actually went with a different approach and just gave that input the readonly="readonly" tag and then it sends it correctly. I updated my jquery to say readonly instead of disabled.

Answer (score 0):

From this site:
http://webdesign.about.com/od/forms/a/aa071805.htm

I can see that "the disabled element will not be successful when submitting the form"

So, disabled form-fields aren't sent

Your jquery code isn't *un*setting the disabled field, so you're setting the value, sure. But you're not sending it.

SOLUTION:

```
// To enable 
$('#payment_amount').removeAttr('disabled');

// OR you can set attr to "" 
$('#payment_amount').attr('disabled', '');
```

(i got that code snippet from
http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-disableenable-element-with.html)

ADDED BONUS:
your jquery hurt my eyes. Why not use

```
$('#remaining_balance').click( function(){
    ...
}
```

Actually, why aren't you using the $ operator at all? Um, you use it instead of the "jquery" keyword.
So, that said, the solution you'd want is (if you want to keep on not using the $ operator):

```
jQuery("#payment_amount").removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: it's because I'm using Wordpress and for the non-conflict it's making me use the jQuery instead of just using $. I only did the .on because I thought the .click function was causing my problem but I know now that I can change it back to that and it shouldn't be an issue.